# Printing user input to the console in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

please I'm having a tough time finding solution to this code, I was asked to print the user input to the console in nodeJs in one of these learning sites. Am a newbie in nodeJs and i don't know how to go about it. Any help with be appreciated. Here is the lines of code. Thanks

```js
'use strict';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.trim().split('\n').map(string => {
        return string.trim();
    });
    
    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

function greeting(parameterVariable) {
    // This line prints 'Hello, World!' to the console:
    console.log('Hello, World!');
    console.log(inputString);
    
}

function main() {
    const parameterVariable = readLine();
    
    greeting(parameterVariable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to open the standard input stream.
Try something like this snippet:

```
// We start listening for input:
const stdin = process.openStdin();
let content = '';

stdin.addListener('data', d => {
  content += d.toString();
});

stdin.addListener('end', () => {
  console.info(`Input: ${content}`);
});
```